# Can we modify the 4th degree polynomial roots formula such that when all the roots are real, all the radicals inside are real as well?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Given the general 4th degree polynomial:
$$
x^4+ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=0
$$

We find on wikipedia the following formula for the roots:
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/99/Quartic_Formula.svg
We can find the same formula on Wolfram alpha when we input $$x^4+ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=0$$

Let pick a particular example, the following polynomial which has roots 1,2,3,4:
$$
(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)=0
$$
Which we can expand into:
$$
x^4-10x^3+35x^2-50x+24=0
$$

All the roots of this polynomial are real(not imaginary) but when we apply the formula from the wikipedia link, some of the radicals are imaginary even though in the end they all cancel each other.

For this particular numerical example, i can easily cancel them it but my problem requires me to solve this problem in variable form.

Now my question, is there a formula which avoids imaginary numbers when all the roots are real numbers? If its too much work to do just tell what technique would you use to simplify all the imaginary radicals.

Comment: Are you familiar with the corresponding problem for roots of cubic polynomials?  On its face the negative answer for cubic polynomials would seem to imply a negative answer for quartic polynomials.

Comment: Im not familiar with that at all. Please explain briefly.

Comment: For some cubic polynomials, there is no algebraic form of the roots without complex numbers. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casus_irreducibilis

Comment: Please see if [*this paper*](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s40819-021-01152-w) helps.  Also with diagrams in [*arxiv*](https://arxiv.org/abs/2008.07529).

Comment: A hybrid way, with radicals and trigonometric functions, of the real roots also mentioned in [*this paper*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.08807).